# How to store an object with cyclic reference during form reload?

Tags: javascript

I have two windows that could be open simultaneously in the browser. The window names are

1. Estimates
2. ActualCosts

My parent window is "ActualCosts". It has a button "View Estimates". On clicking it the Estimates window will be opened. Now when I save something on the Estimates window I want to refresh "ActualCosts" window. That I can easily perform using `window.opener` object. ie,

```
window.opener.location.reload();
```

Now, the tricky scenario. ( Refreshing child wondow while updating parent window )

1. I clicked on the button "View Estimates" on the ActualCosts window
2. so I have a reference to the opened window `var myRef = window.open("estpage.htm");`
3. Can do a reload when I save something on the parent window like this `myRef.location.reload();`
4. Now I changed something on Estimates window and saved. It reloads the parent window and that makes myRef null as the form is reloaded.

My doubt is how to persist the myRef object across window reload. I tried JSON.stringify and store them in `document.cookie` / `window.localStorage` and parse it again as object when needed. As I stringify I get a cyclic reference error and so I use the overload of `JSON.stringify` like this

```
var newWindowReference = window.open(newWindowName);
var seen = [];
var json = JSON.stringify(newWindowReference, function (key, val) {
    if (typeof val == "object") {
        if (seen.indexOf(val) >= 0) { return };
        seen.push(val);
    }
    return val;
});
window.localStorage.setItem("newWindowRef", json);
//CreateCookie(("newWindowRef", json, 0);//length limit a concern too.
```

But this does not work. The parsed object has `myRef.location` as an empty object.
So my doubts are

1. How to persist window.open's object reference across form reloads?
2. Is there another way to refer this opened window?
3. Or is there a generic way to store objects across form reloads?

Any guidance will be deeply appreciated.

P.S: I know that polling for changes is a better option, but my concern is on how to catch the winRef object.

Comment: Show please working code on jsfiddle

Comment: @FSou1: working code in jsfiddle?